# Lock a thread in Disqus or close site for comments

Tags: comments, disqus

Is there any way to lock a thread for comments or to lock down comments on a whole site on Disqus?

Comment: According to http://docs.disqus.com/help/18/ it should be possible to lock a thread. However, I'm unable to find the ID of the thread because the UI on Disqus has changed after this documentation was written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your [Disqus Admin panel](http://disqus.com/admin/moderate/)
2. Find the comment from the thread you want to close.
3. Click anywhere on the comment to expand it.
4. Hover the mouse over the `Find...` button and list menu will appear where the last option is `All comments from this thread`, click it.
5. In the new page, there will be the `Close` button in the right sidebar.

Comment: Thanks! Does this only work from the old interface? I can't find the option in the new interface.

Comment: @grm: I have no idea about the new/old interface differences. I think my instructions are for the new interface.